# Cluster Size is too big after BIRCH clustering

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means, data-analysis, pca, hierarchical-clustering

I have a data of 2,4million row and about 56 variables. I was doing sampling of 10000 data and do PCA into 10 dimensions

Then I use BIRCH clustering as k-means and hierarchical were showing bad silhoutte coefficient. Scikit says that the usecase of BIRCH is large dataset and data reduction

As the result, I get 4 clusters with Silhoutte coefficient of 0,4 (-1 is the worst, 1 is the best) which I think it is good enough. The problem is, the first cluster size is too big, it get 94% of all data, meanwhile the other clusters only get 6%

So my questions are ; Do PCA and Sampling affect the BIRCH clustering result? And what can be done to cluster that dominate the size?

I am thinking of either do re-clustering to the 94% or just accept the fact that 94% of my data is really have the same cluster.
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you are applying a downsampling strategy that doesn't bias towards one type/class  of your data?

Comment: I just random sampling of 10000 rows. Any strategy to make sure it is not bias?

Comment: Maybe your data has one big cluster? If you suspect PCA, why don't you try without?

Comment: yes it has. I have tried to do more sampling and iteration and get more balanced result although one of it still dominate 70%.